# Apply external effects to player movement

Tags: unity, c#, physics, movement

**In a 2D downhill game with the following, custom movement code, how do I apply external effects to the player's movement?**

For example, when the player hits an obstacle, I want them to get *bounced off* the obstacle and *briefly stop* before they are able to continue moving. How do I best integrate those types of external effects into my movement code in a way that is *scalable*?

```
private void UpdatePlayerVelocity()
{
    // Calculate the player's vertical movement speed
    float speedY = maxSpeed.y * Time.fixedDeltaTime;

    // Calculate the player's horizontal movement speed
    float speedX = inputDirectionX * maxSpeed.x * Time.fixedDeltaTime;

    // Set the player's new velocity
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(speedX, speedY);
}
```

My player-obstacle collision is handled in the obstacle class, and I am using an action to notify the player about the collision. So I have the ability to have a corresponding method in the player class that get's called when the collision occurs:

```
public void OnPlayerCollidedWithObstacle(Vector2 collisionNormal)
{
    // TODO:
    // Integrate the following into the above movement code ???
    // 1. Bounce the player off the obstacle
    // 2. Briefly stop the player from moving
    // 3. Continue moving when the player has tapped the screen
}
```

As a first step, I am thinking to wrap my default movement code in a *bool check*, so that it doesn't get run when the collision movement code is run.

**However, I was hoping for a better, more scalable way?**

*PS: I would like to keep my movement code custom, so no Unity physics / AddForce / etc.*

---

**Update - Here is my attempt:**

The following works. However, I am wondering if there is a cleaner / more systematic / more scalable way to handle this?

````
private void UpdatePlayerVelocity()
{
    // If no player-obstacle collision
    // and player has tapped to start/continue moving
    if (obstacleCollisionTimer <= 0 && playerHasTapped)
    {
        // Calculate the player's vertical movement speed
        float speedY = maxSpeed.y * Time.fixedDeltaTime;

        // Calculate the player's horizontal movement speed
        float speedX = inputDirectionX * maxSpeed.x * Time.fixedDeltaTime;

        // Set the player's velocity
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(speedX, speedY);
    }
    // If player-obstacle collision resolved,
    // but player has not yet tapped to continue moving
    else if (obstacleCollisionTimer <= 0 && !playerHasTapped)
    {
        // Don't move
        rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
    }
    // If currenty resolving player-obstacle collsion by bouncing player off
    else
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(-collisionNormal.x, -collisionNormal.y);

        obstacleCollisionTimer -= Time.fixedDeltaTime;
    }
}

public void OnPlayerCollidedWithObstacle(Vector2 collisionNormal)
{
    // Collision normal will be used to bounce the player off the obstacle
    this.collisionNormal = collisionNormal;

    // Duration of the "bounce off" movement
    obstacleCollisionTimer = 0.2f;

    // The player needs to tap for movement to start again
    playerHasTapped = false;            
}
```
````

Comment: Can you identify a specific problem in your current working solution that answers should focus on improving?

Comment: I don't feel it would scale very well, if I added multiple, other effects to the player's movement. With the current solution, I would need to add more bools and more if statements. I feel like that would quickly get out of hand!?

Comment: After a little bit more research, I think I am going to use a state machine as discussed here: https://unity3d.college/2017/05/26/unity3d-design-patterns-state-basic-state-machine/

Comment: If it works for you, I think it's worth writing up as an Answer below. :)